# What is the difference between session and connection in MyBatis?

Tags: jdbc, mybatis

With JDBC, I understand each connection represents a physical tcp connection with database.

But in MyBatis, there is not connections but sessions, so what is the difference between session and connection?

When I open a session or close a session, what happen internal? Is this mean create/close a connection?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, JDBC connection does not represent physical TCP connection. TCP connection basically allows only to do very few operations, the main one to send an array of bytes to the application on the other end of the connection.

JDBC connection *uses* TCP connection underneath but it is a higher level abstraction that allows the application to do the more high level operation, namely, to execute SQL queries.

Similarly, `SQLSession` in mybatis uses JDBC connection but is even more high level concept. Mainly, it allows to execute sql query and map the result to object as specified by the mapping.